# How can I supply federated users with an aws access key id/secret?

Tags: amazon-web-services, saml-2.0, auth0

We're using Auth0 to give (federated) users access to Auth0 (we've followed these instructions for setup: https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/aws#sso-with-the-aws-dashboard)

In Auth0 we've setup a simple rule system where the federated user's group membership maps to one of two different IAM roles, which gives the user either full access or read-only access (or no access at all) in the aws console.

However, I'm struggling to see how I can provide federated users with the means to get an access key id/secret linked to their account. Our wishlist is:

1. The access key id/secret is unique per federated user, and as such is void if the federated user is deleted from the identity provider.
2. I could manually provision a IAM role per federated user and link each user to his/her "personal" IAM role, but I'd obviously prefer not to.

All in all I guess I'd like there to be a "linked" IAM user representing each federated account.

So I guess my question is: How do allow my federated users access to personal access key id's in aws?

Comment: I could be be wrong, but I think you'll find that it's sort of the point of federated access *not* to associate permanent aws access keys with individual users, but to provide *temporary* keys instead.  If you give them permanent keys, there's no way to revoke them if the user is deleted from the identity provider.  If they're deleted, they can't refresh the temporary credentials.  What problem would your idea solve for you?

Comment: Temporary access keys are fine, I don't care if devs have to refresh them at certain intervals.

Comment: See the bottom of the page you linked, *The result of calling the delegation endpoint will contain the AWS token in the `Credentials` field.*  Temporary AWS access key ids start with `ASIA...` rather than `AKIA...`.

Answer (score 0):

Federated users require [temporary access keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html#temporary-access-keys) which you can grant with [`aws sts assume-role`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can create your AWS Accesskey, Secret key & token for the federated users
using [AssumeRoleWithSAML-cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role-with-saml.html)
[AssumeRolewithSAML-sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithSAML.html)

AWS CLI Example that will provide you an credentials for federated user:

> aws sts assume-role-with-saml --role-arn
> arn:aws:iam::AccountNumber:role/ADFS-AWS-ADMIN --principal-arn
> arn:aws:iam::AccountNumber:saml-provider/idp001 --saml-assertion
> 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